# How to reindent tab to 2 spaces in Vim in one line

Tags: vim

I've set tab to 4 spaces on one project and now the other project is 2 spaces. I'd like to convert the second project to 2 spaces for a tab.

I've tried `:set ts=2` and `retab!` but nothing works. I have this block of code.

```
gulp.task('build', () => {
>   if (process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production') {
>   >   gulp.start('build:prod');
>   } else {
>   >   gulp.start('build:dev');
>   }
});
```

I show the tab as `>` using `:set list` I want to convert the whole file to 2 spaces. How do I do that?

Comment: In one line?  If you insist: `:set noet | ret! | set ts=2 | set et | ret!`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A quick & dirty solution would be running a replace command

```
:%s/  / /g
```

The first gap has two spaces and the second has one, so it replaces all pairs of two spaces with one space.  So long as you don't have double spaces elsewhere in the file, it'll work a treat.  If you do, you can go nuclear:

```
:%s/    /  /g
```

That's four spaces in the first gap and two in the second :).

Comment: Test this: `:%s/\t/  /g` <= Replace all tab with two spaces

Answer (score 1):

1. Tabs to space

`:set ts=2
:setlocal expandtab<CR>:retab<CR>`

2. using space only

`:normal ggVG=
:set ts=2
:setlocal expandtab<CR>:retab`